# Web Widget using html, js and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-widget

I am building a web widget using javascript only and not using iframe. I want my web widget not to use page's css. I cant use custom css and also don't want to use iframe as it will not be user friendly.

How can i restrict my web widget not to use page's css. As my web widget will return html code and that html uses that page css.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing like CSS reset: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

It basically resets all css properties for a given subtree.

Comment: Yeah, but if he can't use custom CSS he can't drop a reset in I'd imagine.

Comment: Inline css in html file?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a winner. Like, the most awful winner ever but technically a winner :'D

Comment: @EriksKlotins inline css wont stop Page's css to interact with other html tags.